# How can I time the length of a drag/drop event on a HTML5 canvas? (KineticJS)

Tags: javascript, timer, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am trying to create an application in which a user is required to drag a *Kinetic.Image* object for a requisite length of time (in this case 5 seconds); this is going to be used to ensure that they do not move on to the next stage without having performed the task in hand. I am using KineticJS for my application. Is this possible with some combination of the dragstart, dragmove and dragend event handlers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've now come up with a solution myself, so putting it here for anyone who may be interested. The simplest way to do this, I believe, is to just take a timestamp in the dragstart and do the same in the dragend and perform a diff. Increment a global counter variable with the difference, and then do a check in the dragend to see if that counter is over the required amount.

```
object1.on("dragstart", function() { lastTimestamp = Date.now(); });
object1.on("dragend", function() { timeTaken = Date.now() - lastTimestamp; });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var count = 0;
 function Tick() {
     count++;
     window.setTimeout("Tick()", 1000);
 }

 myObject.on('dragstart', function(){
     Tick();
 });

 myObject.on('dragend', function(){
     return count;
 }
```

I'm not sure if this is a good way to do it, but you can use either setTimeout or setInterval to increment a variable 'count' and then return that variable when dragging is finished.

If you want a native KineticJS implementation, you'll have to use Kinetic.Animation as it has a built in 'frame.time' which will count milliseconds for you, but that's a bit messy if you want just drag events.

Comment: Thanks for your post -- I've already come up with a working solution myself now, but couldn't post it for a certain amount of time due to my low reputation score (there is a time limit for answering your own question for some reason!) Cheers.